# Maximum number of bits in custom primitive types?

Tags: types, julia

I now understood this is not a good idea, but only to be precise, which is the maximum number of bits in a custom primitive type (the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Primitive-Types-1) just says it must be a multiple of 8):

```
primitive type My10MBBuffer 83886080 end
```

(that would result in a `invalid number of bits in primitive type My10MBBuffer` error)

I think the julia source of that error is:

```
   ssize_t nb = jl_unbox_long(vnb);
    if (nb < 1 || nb >= (1 << 23) || (nb & 7) != 0)
        jl_errorf("invalid number of bits in primitive type %s",
jl_symbol_name((jl_sym_t*)name));
```

[EDIT:]

From a trial & error that number seems to be 8388600 (8*(1024*1024-1)) bits.

Why is that and why it is bad to use a custom primitive type to host a large amount of data ?

Comment: I guess that's limited by physical data bus width.

Comment: Why would you want a primitive type that big? Why not use an array of bytes in that case? This seems like a misuse of the ability to create primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of bits you can set for a primitive type is

```
8388600 bits
```

This limit comes from the code

```
    if (nb < 1 || nb >= (1 << 23) || (nb & 7) != 0)
        jl_errorf("invalid number of bits in primitive type %s",
                   jl_symbol_name((jl_sym_t*)name));
```

in [interpreter.c](http://%20https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/8c445663547791e59f33f9e8d49b276332107614/src/interpreter.c#L191) of Julia source code.

`1 << 23` is 1 MB (1024*1024 bytes). So your primitive type must be at least one byte less than 1 MB, which makes the maximum 8388600 bits.

As for why this is chosen to be the limit, I would only guess 1 MB is chosen because the stack size on most operating systems is not really big. (default is 1 or 2 MB)

I guess if you recompile Julia with the above code changed, you can adjust this limit, I do not see any other reason apart from the stack size why this limit should be 1 MB, though I do not really know why you would want that.